# How to implement Timeout in BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler Python

Tags: python, basehttpserver

In my python script, I am trying to run a web server:

```
server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('127.0.0.1',8080), RequestHandler)
```

I have a request handler class:

```
class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        # Doing Some Stuff.
```

Now I always wait for some data to catch in do_GET. I want to implement a timeout operation where I want this web server to close after lets say 60 seconds. I am not able to implement that. Please suggest me how can I implement auto shut down operation for web server in this scenario.

Thanks 
Tara Singh

Answer (score 12):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you can't implement a read timeout in `do_GET` since the request has already been read by the time this method is called.

Since `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` extends `StreamRequestHandler` which in turn extends [`BaseRequestHandler`](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html#requesthandler-objects), you can override `setup()` to initialise the socket with a timeout:

```
class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  def setup(self):
    BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.setup(self)
    self.request.settimeout(60)

  def do_GET(self):
    # ...
```

Comment: I already tried this, its not working. Do I need to override any other method along with setup? I just want server to shut down on its own no matter what is is processing after lets say 60 seconds.

Comment: You should do `self.timeout = 60` before calling the base class' `setup()` method (internally it makes a call to `settimeout` based on this setting.)

Answer (score 8):

I actually found that setting a value for self.timeout in def setup didn't work if I then called the superclass. It looks like the Handler's setup and **init** methods aren't called during creation of the HTTPServer instance. I used pydevd to confirm this.

So, I took a backward step:

```
httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(server_address, MyHttpHandler)
httpd.timeout = 10
```

Which works perfectly, and without overriding core code, or building your own derivative classes. It looks like you'd have to overwrite the HTTPServer code, rather than the Handler code, if you wanted to do it that way.

Comment: Can somebody confirm that this works? It looks to be by far the easiest solution!

Comment: I'm using it on production code (python 2.7.11). If it wasn't working for me, then my code wouldn't work. I've tested varying the figure, and it's easy to see it working, because when I remove it my process hangs until it gets an http request, which could be hours later.

Comment: This does **not** work if you call [serve_forever](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socketserver.html#SocketServer.BaseServer.serve_forever) afterwards (which most people probably do). Setting the `timeout` attribute of the `StreamRequestHandler` (as others have advised) always works though (but it's not [documented](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4845aa6ef813313051db34726afc76c0e7dc5fee/Lib/SocketServer.py#L691)).

Comment: Worked for my use case. I'm using httpd.handle_request(). Tried various ways until I found this. Thanks!

Comment: That's interesting, so the behaviour is different whether you are using serve_forever or handle_request? I wonder if that's intended or not.

Answer (score 3):

```
class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    timeout = 60 # StreamRequestHandler.setup
    def do_GET(self):
        # Doing Some Stuff.
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/360251/edit) your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get timeouts working for HTTP requests with

```
self.rfile._sock.settimeout(60)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

```
timeout = 0.1  # seconds

class WebHTTPServer(BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer):
    def server_bind(self):
        BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
        self.socket.settimeout(timeout)

class WebReqHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    <etc> 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = WebHTTPServer(('',port), WebReqHandler)
    while 1:
        server.handle_request()
        <do other things>
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by [Tey'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5099839/tey) in [TinBane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1285014/tinbane)'s answer, `timeout` attribute will not work with `serve_forever()` method, as stated in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver.BaseServer.timeout):

[image: server_forever]

The workaround is to use a custom loop for handling the request as pointed out by [user3483992](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3483992/user3483992)

```
while True: server.handle_request()
```

`handle_request()` will then trigger the method `handle_timeout()` at the end of the given timeout as expected:

[image]

...except the handle_timeout method is doing nothing:

[image]

A solution is then to provide another implementation for this method, such as (credit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294618/define-a-lambda-expression-that-raises-an-exception)):

```
server.handle_timeout = lambda: (_ for _ in ()).throw(TimeoutError())
```

In short:

```
try:
     server = HTTPServer(('', PORT_NUMBER), `yourAwesomeRequestHandler`)
     server.timeout = 10
     server.handle_timeout = lambda: (_ for _ in ()).throw(TimeoutError())
     while True: server.handle_request()
except TimeoutError:
    // TODO
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):
    BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, request, client_address, server)   
    self.timeout = 60
```

Comment: The `self.timeout = 60` needs to be set before the call to the super class's constructor in order to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Given the popularity of python's http.server module, a minimal drop-in copy-pasteable replacement for `python3 -m http.server` with a timeout is likely useful for others that find this page:

~20 second timeout:

```bash
python3 -c "from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import time
start = time.time()
httpd = HTTPServer(('', 8000), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
while not time.time() - start > 20:
    httpd.handle_request()"
```