# Define a lambda expression that raises an Exception

Tags: python

How can I write a lambda expression that's equivalent to:

```
def x():
    raise Exception()
```

The following is not allowed:

```
y = lambda : raise Exception()
```

Comment: So you can't do that. Use normal functions.

Comment: What is the point of giving a name to an anonymous function?

Comment: @gnibbler You can use the name to refer to the function. y() is easier to use than (lambda : 0)() in the REPL.

Comment: So what is the advantage of `y=lambda...` over `def y:` then?

Comment: @gnibbler Some context: I wanted to define a function def g(f, e) that calls f in the happy case and e if an error was detected. Depending on the scenario e could raise an exception or return some valid value. To use g I wanted to write g(lambda x: x *2, lambda e: raise e) or alternatively g(lambda x: x * 2, lambda e : 0).

Comment: Just in case anyone else comes here looking for a way to raise an exception as part of a pytest monkeypatch (or equivalent), I ended up using the monkeypatch to hit a fixture that used the side_effect argument to Mock like this: `def mock_urlopen():
    return Mock(spec=urllib2.urlopen, side_effect=urllib2.URLError('Fake URLError Exception'))`

Comment: If you reached here since you want to raise an exception in a mock, then use: [side_effect()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect)

Comment: @JohnLaRooy For posterity, there is none. [Named lambdas are bad practice](/q/38381556/4518341). Use a `def` instead.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

There is more than one way to skin a Python:

```
y = lambda: (_ for _ in ()).throw(Exception('foobar'))
```

---

Lambdas accept statements. Since `raise ex` is a statement, you could write a general purpose raiser:

```
def raise_(ex):
    raise ex

y = lambda: raise_(Exception('foobar'))
```

But if your goal is to avoid a `def`, this obviously doesn't cut it. It does, however allow you to conditionally raise exceptions, e.g.:

```
y = lambda x: 2*x if x < 10 else raise_(Exception('foobar'))
```

---

Alternatively you can raise an exception without defining a named function. All you need is a strong stomach (and 2.x for the given code):

```
type(lambda:0)(type((lambda:0).func_code)(
  1,1,1,67,'|\0\0\202\1\0',(),(),('x',),'','',1,''),{}
)(Exception())
```

And a python3 *strong stomach* solution:

```
type(lambda: 0)(type((lambda: 0).__code__)(
    1,0,1,1,67,b'|\0\202\1\0',(),(),('x',),'','',1,b''),{}
)(Exception())
```

---

Thanks @WarrenSpencer for pointing out a very simple answer if you don't care which exception is raised: `y = lambda: 1/0`.

Comment: OMG what dark art it is?

Comment: If you don't care what type of exception is thrown, the following also works: `lambda: 1 / 0`.  You'll just end up with a ZeroDivisionError being thrown instead of a regular exception.  Bear in mind that if the exception is allowed to propogate, it may look strange to someone debugging your code to start seeing a bunch of ZeroDivisionErrors.

Comment: Great solution @WarrenSpencer. Most code doesn't have a lot of zero division errors, so it's as distinctive as if you could choose the type yourself.

Comment: @WarrenSpencer great suggestion! I've added it to the answer.

Comment: `y = 1/0` is super smart solution if Exception type is irrelevant

Comment: Can anyone talk us through what is actually going on in the 'dark-art/strong stomach' solutions?

Comment: Like the Update 2 most.  #SkinThePython !

Comment: The 'strong stomach' solution is some awesome code golf! For details search for bytecode in Google and in a notebook `help(type(lambda: 0)) `and `help((lambda: 0).__code__)` and look at the module `dis`. There are two cool parts. The builtin classes `function` and `code` are not exposed, else it would be `function(code( 13 arguments),{})(Exception)`. `lambda: 0` just returns a `function` instance, for which we need the class, hence the `type(lambda: 0)`. An alternative is `(lambda:0).__class__`. `help(code)` and `dis` explain 13 args, but `b'|\0\202\1\0'` is the bytecode string, see `compile`

Comment: Tagging on to @WarrenSpencer's approach, `lambda: n` works as long as you can ensure that `n` is not defined in the scope where the lambda is defined (you raise `NameError` this way). Even defining `n` in the scope where the lambda is *used* doesn't prevent the exception (if that's a different scope).

Comment: I guess you could also do `lambda: [][1]` for an `IndexError`, `lambda: {}['']` for `KeyError`, `lambda: ''+0` for `TypeError` etc.

Answer (score 92):

How about using [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec), a built-in function in Python 3?

```
lambda x: exec('raise(Exception(x))')
```

Comment: It is quite hacky but for writing tests where you want to mock functions this works neat !!!

Comment: Works but you shouldn't do it.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I get a `SyntaxError` on Python 2.7.11.

Comment: I am also getting the above error (SyntaxError) on Python 2.7.5

Comment: This works with Python 3.6. Maybe to file a bug to Python 2.7.5?

Comment: this is specific to python 3 however I don't think python 2 allows that.

Comment: @kannanEkanath , you called this hacky? Comparing to the currently most-upvoted and accepted answer, this answer feels like a breeze. It at least uses the `exec()` in its expected way. I've upvoted this answer. It is just unfortunate that it does not work in Python 2.

Comment: @augurar Why should we not use this solution? If it's because `exec()` is dangerous, is that even relevant here when the argument to `exec()` is hard-coded? If I have enough access to the code base to change that string, then adding a line above to read `import os; os.system('destroy all the things')` would be just as easy. Is there another reason I don't know of why you're recommending against this? Textbooks always stop at "Just don't", which doesn't help anyone understand the possible dangers.

Comment: True, this looks really good and I will probably use it. I'm guessing people are saying not to because of the ability of the exec function, but not necessarily this use of it.

Answer (score 33):

I'd like to give an explanation of the **UPDATE 3** of the answer provided by Marcelo Cantos:

```py
type(lambda: 0)(type((lambda: 0).__code__)(
    1,0,1,1,67,b'|\0\202\1\0',(),(),('x',),'','',1,b''),{}
)(Exception())
```

## Explanation

`lambda: 0` is an instance of the `builtins.function` class.
`type(lambda: 0)` is the `builtins.function` class.
`(lambda: 0).__code__` is a `code` object.
A `code` object is an object which holds the compiled bytecode among other things.
It is defined here in CPython https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/code.h.
Its methods are implemented here https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/codeobject.c.
We can run the help on the code object:

```
Help on code object:

class code(object)
 |  code(argcount, kwonlyargcount, nlocals, stacksize, flags, codestring,
 |        constants, names, varnames, filename, name, firstlineno,
 |        lnotab[, freevars[, cellvars]])
 |  
 |  Create a code object.  Not for the faint of heart.
```

`type((lambda: 0).__code__)` is the code class.
So when we say

```py
type((lambda: 0).__code__)(
    1,0,1,1,67,b'|\0\202\1\0',(),(),('x',),'','',1,b'')
```

we are calling the constructor of the code object with the following arguments:

- argcount=1
- kwonlyargcount=0
- nlocals=1
- stacksize=1
- flags=67
- codestring=b'|\0\202\1\0'
- constants=()
- names=()
- varnames=('x',)
- filename=''
- name=''
- firstlineno=1
- lnotab=b''

You can read about what the arguments mean in the definition of the `PyCodeObject`
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/code.h.
The value of 67 for the `flags` argument is for example `CO_OPTIMIZED | CO_NEWLOCALS | CO_NOFREE`.

The most importand argument is the `codestring` which contains instruction opcodes.
Let's see what they mean.

```py
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(b'|\0\202\1\0')
          0 LOAD_FAST                0 (0)
          2 RAISE_VARARGS            1
          4 <0>
```

The documentation of opcodes can by found here
https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/dis.html#python-bytecode-instructions.
The first byte is the opcode for `LOAD_FAST`, the second byte is its argument i.e. 0.

```
LOAD_FAST(var_num)
    Pushes a reference to the local co_varnames[var_num] onto the stack.
```

So we push the reference to `x` onto the stack. The `varnames` is a list of strings containing only 'x'.
We will push the only argument of the function we are defining to the stack.

The next byte is the opcode for `RAISE_VARARGS` and the next byte is its argument i.e. 1.

```
RAISE_VARARGS(argc)
    Raises an exception using one of the 3 forms of the raise statement, depending on the value of argc:
        0: raise (re-raise previous exception)
        1: raise TOS (raise exception instance or type at TOS)
        2: raise TOS1 from TOS (raise exception instance or type at TOS1 with __cause__ set to TOS)
```

The TOS is the top-of-stack.
Since we pushed the first argument (`x`) of our function to the stack and `argc` is 1 we will raise the
`x` if it is an exception instance or make an instance of `x` and raise it otherwise.

The last byte i.e. 0 is not used. It is not a valid opcode. It might as well not be there.

Going back to code snippet we are anylyzing:

```py
type(lambda: 0)(type((lambda: 0).__code__)(
    1,0,1,1,67,b'|\0\202\1\0',(),(),('x',),'','',1,b''),{}
)(Exception())
```

We called the constructor of the code object:

```py
type((lambda: 0).__code__)(
    1,0,1,1,67,b'|\0\202\1\0',(),(),('x',),'','',1,b'')
```

We pass the code object and an empty dictionary to the constructor of a function object:

```py
type(lambda: 0)(type((lambda: 0).__code__)(
    1,0,1,1,67,b'|\0\202\1\0',(),(),('x',),'','',1,b''),{}
)
```

Let's call help on a function object to see what the arguments mean.

```
Help on class function in module builtins:

class function(object)
 |  function(code, globals, name=None, argdefs=None, closure=None)
 |  
 |  Create a function object.
 |  
 |  code
 |    a code object
 |  globals
 |    the globals dictionary
 |  name
 |    a string that overrides the name from the code object
 |  argdefs
 |    a tuple that specifies the default argument values
 |  closure
 |    a tuple that supplies the bindings for free variables
```

We then call the constructed function passing an Exception instance as an argument.
Consequently we called a lambda function which raises an exception.
Let's run the snippet and see that it indeed works as intended.

```py
>>> type(lambda: 0)(type((lambda: 0).__code__)(
...     1,0,1,1,67,b'|\0\202\1\0',(),(),('x',),'','',1,b''),{}
... )(Exception())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "", line 1, in 
Exception
```

## Improvements

We saw that the last byte of the bytecode is useless. Let's not clutter this
complicated expression needlesly. Let's remove that byte.
Also if we want to golf a little we could omit the instantiation of Exception
and instead pass the Exception class as an argument. Those changes would result
in the following code:

```py
type(lambda: 0)(type((lambda: 0).__code__)(
    1,0,1,1,67,b'|\0\202\1',(),(),('x',),'','',1,b''),{}
)(Exception)
```

When we run it we will get the same result as before. It's just shorter.

Comment: This is horrific. I love it.

Answer (score 19):

Actually, there is a way, but it's very contrived.

You can create a code object using the `compile()` built-in function.  This allows you to use the `raise` statement (or any other statement, for that matter), but it raises another challenge: executing the code object.  The usual way would be to use the `exec` statement, but that leads you back to the original problem, namely that you can't execute statements in a `lambda` (or an `eval()`, for that matter).

The solution is a hack.  Callables like the result of a `lambda` statement all have an attribute `__code__`, which can actually be replaced.  So, if you create a callable and replace it's `__code__` value with the code object from above, you get something that can be evaluated without using statements.  Achieving all this, though, results in very obscure code:

`map(lambda x, y, z: x.__setattr__(y, z) or x, [lambda: 0], ["__code__"], [compile("raise Exception", "", "single"])[0]()`

The above does the following:

- the `compile()` call creates a code object that raises the exception;
- the `lambda: 0` returns a callable that does nothing but return the value 0 -- this is used to execute the above code object later;
- the `lambda x, y, z` creates a function that calls the `__setattr__` method of the first argument with the remaining arguments, AND RETURNS THE FIRST ARGUMENT!  This is necessary, because `__setattr__` itself returns `None`;
- the `map()` call takes the result of `lambda: 0`, and using the `lambda x, y, z` replaces it's `__code__` object with the result of the `compile()` call.  The result of this map operation is a list with one entry, the one returned by `lambda x, y, z`, which is why we need this `lambda`: if we would use `__setattr__` right away, we would lose the reference to the `lambda: 0` object!
- finally, the first (and only) element of the list returned by the `map()` call is executed, resulting in the code object being called, ultimately raising the desired exception.

It works (tested in Python 2.6), but it's definitely not pretty.

One last note: if you have access to the `types` module (which would require to use the `import` statement before your `eval`), then you can shorten this code down a bit: using `types.FunctionType()` you can create a function that will execute the given code object, so you won't need the hack of creating a dummy function with `lambda: 0` and replacing the value of its `__code__` attribute.

Answer (score 17):

If all you want is a lambda expression that raises an arbitrary exception, you can accomplish this with an illegal expression. For instance, `lambda x: [][0]` will attempt to access the first element in an empty list, which will raise an IndexError.

**PLEASE NOTE**: This is a hack, not a feature. **Do not** use this in any (non code-golf) code that another human being might see or use.

Comment: In my case I get: `TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)`. Are you sure of the IndexError?

Comment: Yep. Did you perhaps provide the wrong number of arguments? If you need a lambda function that can take any number of arguments, use `lambda *x: [][0]`. (The original version only takes one argument; for no arguments, use `lambda : [][0]`; for two, use `lambda x,y: [][0]`; etc.)

Comment: I've expanded this a little:  
`lambda x: {}["I want to show this message.  Called with: %s" % x]`     Produces:   `KeyError: 'I want to show this message.  Called with: foo'`

Comment: @ErlVolton Clever! Though using this anywhere except in a one-off script seems like a terrible idea...

Comment: I'm temporarily using in unit tests for a project where I haven't bothered to make a real mock of my logger.  It raises if you try to log an error or critical.  So... Yes terrible, although consensual :)

Comment: This is actually great, no messy code and raises random exception - so unless I need to raise a specific one, this is good.

Comment: @TomášZato Again, I wouldn't recommend this for production code. Keep in mind that someone else will at some point need to maintain the code, so even if you catch the exception yourself, someone will still at some point look at this and wonder what on earth is going on. A comment might help, but Python should typically be self-documenting. So consider defining an actual function instead which throws a specific exception.

Comment: @KyleStrand Who said something about production code? I just wanted to check what happens when XMLRPCServer function throws error - whether client sees it or server crashes.

Comment: That sounds like a perfect use of this "hack" :)

Comment: You don't need that `x`. Just `lambda: [][0]` would do. But then if we are heading to this direction, I would rather do `lambda:1/0` which is at least shorter, when everything else is being equal ... I mean equally bad for readability. :-)

Comment: @RayLuo You need however many arguments are required by the context, of course. See my comment above.

Answer (score 15):

Functions created with lambda forms [cannot contain statements](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#lambda).

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't really answer the question; raising an exception from a lambda expression is easy to do (and catching it may sometimes be achieved by using very contrived tricks, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50916686/2560053 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/50961836/2560053 ).

Answer (score 11):

Every time I have wanted to do this, it was in a test where I wanted to assert that a function was not called.

For this use case, I found it clearer to use a mock with a side effect

```
from unittest.mock import Mock
MyClass.my_method = Mock(side_effect=AssertionError('we should not reach this method call')
```

It would also work in other settings, but I'd rather not depend on unittest in my main application

Comment: Aww man. That's such a sane solution after reading all the other options :)

Comment: For your purpose you can use `assert_not_called` of mock objects. That's more convenient way of ensuring a method was not called.

Answer (score 9):

All the solutions above do work but I think this one is the shortest in case you just need any function that raises a random exception:

```
lambda: 0/0
```

et voila!

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple invalid operation in your Lambda function that results in the desired exception:

```
>>> (1).a
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'a'

>>> [][1]
IndexError: list index out of range

>>> {}['']
KeyError: ''

# this one can even hold a custom text
>>> {}['use foo or bar']
KeyError: 'use foo or bar'

>>> ''+0
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

>>> 1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Use it like `lambda: <operation>`, e.g. `lambda: 1/0`.

---

<sub>This answer is based on [Saher Ahwal’s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294618/define-a-lambda-expression-that-raises-an-exception#comment88052736_8294654) and [Karl Knechtel’s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294618/define-a-lambda-expression-that-raises-an-exception#comment123540438_8294654) comments. It’s a [Community Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) post, feel free to extend the list above.</sub>