# Is there a standard approach to returning values from coroutine endpoints

Tags: python, parsing, design-patterns, coroutine

*My question:*

I would like to know if there is a "best practice" pattern in Python for returning values from coroutine endpoints (aka the "sink" or "consumer"). More generally, how would you approach the following scenario?

*My scenario:*

I have my `(producer) > (filter) > (consumer)` coroutine pipeline to process a text-based table and to build a list of dictionaries from it. I would like the object that is built in `consumer` to be returned to the original caller of `producer`.

*My approach:*

My approach has been to set up a unique *finish-processing* signal that each coroutine checks for. If it hears the signal, then it passes on the signal to its child and yields the returned value. The `consumer` just yields its current value.

*Alternative approaches:*

I considered:

- Using a global to hold the desired object to be "returned" to the caller.
- A class-based approach with regular subroutines.

Reasons why I should maybe reconsider these for my scenario would also be welcome.

*My implementation:*

Here is a simplified version of what I have done, with all key components included.

```
import uuid

FINISH_PROCESSING_SIGNAL = uuid.uuid4()

def coroutine(func):
    def start(*args,**kwargs):
        cr = func(*args,**kwargs)
        cr.next()
        return cr
    return start


# Sink
@coroutine
def list_builder():
    # accepts objects and adds them to a list
    _list = []
    try:
        while True:
            data = (yield)
            if data is FINISH_PROCESSING_SIGNAL:
                yield _list
                break
            _list.append(data)
    except GeneratorExit:
        pass

# Filter
@coroutine
def user_data_filter(target=None):

    if target is None:
        target = list_builder()

    header = "-+-"
    footer = "Transfer Packets"
    username = "User Name"
    fullname = "Full Name"
    note = "Description"

    try:
        while True:
            user = {}
            data = (yield)
            if data is FINISH_PROCESSING_SIGNAL:
                yield target.send(FINISH_PROCESSING_SIGNAL)
                break
            line = data
            if header in line:
                while True:
                    line = (yield)
                    if footer in line:
                        target.send(user)
                        break
                    elif username in line:
                        user["username"] = line.split('|')[1]
                    elif fullname in line:
                        user["fullname"] = line.split('|')[1]
                    elif note in line:
                        user["note"] = line.split('|')[1]

    except GeneratorExit:
        target.close()

# Producer
def process_users_table(table, target=None):

    if target is None:
        target = user_data_filter()

    lines = table.split('\r\n')
    for line in lines:
        target.send(line)
    processed_data = target.send(FINISH_PROCESSING_SIGNAL)
    return processed_data



if __name__ == '__main__':

    test_users_table = \
    """
    Item            |Value\r\n
    ----------------+-----------------------\r\n
    User Name       |alice\r\n
    Full Name       |Alice Doe\r\n
    Description     |\r\n
    Transfer Packets|0\r\n
    ----------------+-----------------------\r\n
    User Name       |bob\r\n
    Full Name       |Bob Tables\r\n
    Description     |\r\n
    Transfer Packets|0\r\n
    """

    users = process_users_table(test_users_table)
    print users
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method of signaling the consumer to terminate is fine and is in harmony with what you would do if using a multiprocessing or threaded Queue. However, generators also have a way to throw Exceptions (rather than sending values) and [the purpose of `throw`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11485591/190597) is precisely to signal events or changes in state to the generator. Moreover, [when an exception is thrown to a generator](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/),

> [i]f the
>       generator catches the exception and yields another value, that is
>       the return value of g.throw().

That seems perfectly suited for your use case. Instead of sending a `FINISH_PROCESSING_SIGNAL` value, you could throw a `FINISH_PROCESSING_SIGNAL` Exception, and use `try..except` to yield the final value.

```
class FINISH_PROCESSING_SIGNAL(Exception): pass

def coroutine(func):
    def start(*args,**kwargs):
        cr = func(*args,**kwargs)
        cr.next()
        return cr
    return start


# Sink
@coroutine
def list_builder():
    # accepts objects and adds them to a list
    _list = []
    try:
        while True:
            data = (yield)
            _list.append(data)
    except FINISH_PROCESSING_SIGNAL:
        yield _list

# Filter
@coroutine
def user_data_filter(target=list_builder()):
    header = "-+-"
    footer = "Transfer Packets"
    username = "User Name"
    fullname = "Full Name"
    note = "Description"
    try:
        while True:
            user = {}
            data = (yield)
            line = data
            if header in line:
                while True:
                    line = (yield)
                    if footer in line:
                        target.send(user)
                        break
                    elif username in line:
                        user["username"] = line.split('|')[1]
                    elif fullname in line:
                        user["fullname"] = line.split('|')[1]
                    elif note in line:
                        user["note"] = line.split('|')[1]
    except FINISH_PROCESSING_SIGNAL as err:
        # Pass along the Exception to the target, and yield its result back
        # to the caller
        yield target.throw(err)

# Producer
def process_users_table(table, target=user_data_filter()):
    lines = table.split('\r\n')
    for line in lines:
        target.send(line)
    processed_data = target.throw(FINISH_PROCESSING_SIGNAL)
    # processed_data = target.close()
    return processed_data



if __name__ == '__main__':

    test_users_table = \
    """
    Item            |Value\r\n
    ----------------+-----------------------\r\n
    User Name       |alice\r\n
    Full Name       |Alice Doe\r\n
    Description     |\r\n
    Transfer Packets|0\r\n
    ----------------+-----------------------\r\n
    User Name       |bob\r\n
    Full Name       |Bob Tables\r\n
    Description     |\r\n
    Transfer Packets|0\r\n
    """

    users = process_users_table(test_users_table)
    print users
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I think throwing an exception-as-signal like this feels a little cleaner than my conditional-break. At least my method doesn't break any obvious taboos. Cheers.