# One-line raise if

Tags: python

I'm trying to condense `raise if` to one line. I had:

```
def hey(self, message):
    if not message:
        raise ValueError("message must be a string")
```

It works, but this code doesn't work:

```
def hey(self, message):
    raise ValueError("message must be a string") if not message
```

I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. What do I do?

Comment: [`condition expressions`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) require an `else` clause too, hence the syntax error.

Comment: @hcwhsa thats the point I missed. Thanks!

Comment: "Condensing" this to a one-liner is not pythonic,  just keep it as it is. As a side note, an empty string evaluates to False, so either your test is broken or your message error is wrong.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers didn't know this type conversion, it makes a difference.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers would this be ok? `if not message and message != '':
    raise ValueError("message is %s." % message)`

Comment: @leemour, `str.format` should be preferred to the `%` formatting: `"message is {}.".format(message)`.

Comment: @leemour, Is an empty string is also acceptable?

Comment: FYI, `0` also considered False if it is used as predicate in Python. (Empty sequences, empty dictionaries, `None`, ..., too)

Comment: @falsetru yeah, empty string is ok, thanks for the `.format` tip! I do come from Ruby background so I'm used to stricter typing.

Comment: @leemour : if message is a string, then `not message and message != ''` is redundant since the empty string has a false value. FWIW _all_ python objects have a truth value, which defaults to True unless the class says otherwise, cf http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`... if predicate` is invalid in Python. (Are you coming from Ruby?)

Use following:

```
if not message: raise ValueError("message must be a string")
```

---

To check whether the given message is string type, use `isinstance`:

```
>>> isinstance('aa', str) # OR  isinstance(.., basestring) in Python 2.x
True
>>> isinstance(11, str)
False
>>> isinstance('', str)
True
```

`not message` does not do what you want.

```
>>> not 'a string'
False
>>> not ''
True
>>> not [1]
False
>>> not []
True
```

---

```
if not message and message != '':
    raise ValueError("message is invalid: {!r}".format(message))
```

Comment: another option is he is influenced by list comprehensions

Comment: I don't want to explicitly validate if it's a string as it's against [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). Probably, the error message isn't correct but I couldn't come up with a better one.

Comment: @leemour, How about `"message is empty."` ?

Comment: @falsetru this validation checks against `False` as well, but I think your message is better:)

Comment: @leemour, If `True` is passed, what should happen?

Answer (score 5):

Python supports

```
expression_a if xxx else expression_b
```

which's equal to:

```c
xxx ? expression_a : expression_b
```

in other languages, like C.

But

```
statement_a if xxx
```

is not acceptable.

Comment: `statement_*` should be `expression_*`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option that can give fairly condensed syntax without some of the drawbacks of `assert` (such as it disappearing when optimization flags are used):

```
def raiseif(cond, msg="", exc=AssertionError):
    if cond:
        raise exc(msg)
```

Applying to this specific question:

```
def hey(self, message):
    raiseif(
        not isinstance(message, str),
        msg="message must be a string",
        exc=ValueError
    )
```

Comment: This is longer than the code the OP wanted to condense, and adds the additional cost of calling an additional function.

Comment: Fair point on the additional cost of the function call. Regarding the code length, it's actually the same length if you remove the keyword arg names and incorporate the `isinstance` logic as suggested in the top answer. It's `if not isinstance(message, str): raise ValueError("message must be a string")` vs `raiseif(not isinstance(message, str), "message must be a string", ValueError)`. Generalizing, the `raiseif` function will be more compact than the standard if/raise approach if you are looking for something similar to `assert` that doesn't get removed with -O. That's how I got here.

Comment: This idea is quite useful for improving [Cyclomatic Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) score in [Radon](https://radon.readthedocs.io/)

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it seems you are asking how to check if the input is a string type. Based on the updated answer from @falsetru, I would suggest the following. Note that I have changed the error to `TypeError` as it is more appropriate for this case

```
def hey(msg):
    if not isinstance(msg, str): raise TypeError
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/8294654/831399 you could do this

```python
def hey(self, message):
  (_ for _ in ()).throw(ValueError("message must be a string")) if not message else None
```

But it's not really that elegant....