# How to change method implementation without changing it to be not static

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda, static-methods

For example:

```
class a:
    @staticmethod
    def aaa():
        print 'a'

a.aaa()
a.aaa = lambda: raise ValueError('a')
a.aaa()
```

The second time python raises an error that I didn't pass an instance of class a into the method.
How can I change the implementation without removing the static property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Call the `staticmethod` decorator on it directly**:

```
class a:
    @staticmethod
    def aaa():
        print 'a'

a.aaa()
# decorate the lambda expression with staticmethod
a.aaa = staticmethod(lambda: 'a')
a.aaa()
```

This is basically what you do when you use a decorator.

Note that you **can not `raise` an error directly**, since `raise` is a *statement*, not an *expression*. You can however [use some tricks to raise an exception in a *lambda expression*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8294654/67579).