# Lambda function calculator returns function object instead of calculator result

Tags: python, function

i used this page to create lambda exception handler. [How to catch exceptions using python lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45803245/how-to-catch-exceptions-using-python-lambdas)

but when i implemented this in my code

```
        #exception handler
        def executeFunction(x, y):
            try:
                z = lambda x,y : int(x) + int(y)
                return z
            except:
                print('Exception caught')

        if str(dzialanie)=='+':
            print("result is: "  + str(executeFunction(input("input 1st number: "), input("input 2nd number: "))))
```

...

I'm receiving this message:

```
to add two numbers type '+'
to subtract two numbers type '-'
to multiply two numbers type'*'
to divide two numbers type '/'
to exit type 'q'

 which operation you want to choose? +
input 1st number: 13
input 2nd number: 13
result is: .executeFunction.. at 0x00000162200C4288>

to add two numbers type '+'
to subtract two numbers type '-'
to multiply two numbers type'*'
to divide two numbers type '/'
to exit type 'q'

 which operation you want to choose?
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You create the lambda but never execute it: `z(x, y)`

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want `z = x + y`? I don't see why you need to define any function, with either a `lambda` expression or a `def` statement.

Comment: And don't catch an exception if all you are going to do is print a generic message acknowledging it. Either *handle* the exception, or let it go uncaught.

Comment: Um, because that is what your code is doing, defining a function (a lambda is just a function) and then you return it. I.e., you basically do `z = lambda x,y : int(x) + int(y)` then `return z`, what were you **expecting**? Note, you shouldn't use `lambda` if you are going to assign it to a name. That defeats the *entire purpose* of lambda, which is to create an *anonymous function*. It is explicitly against PEP8 style guidelines. Just use `def`.

Comment: Why are you using `try: ... except` anyway? You should almost never use a bare except clause, and in any case, your code in the `try` wouldn't raise any errors. It isn't clear to me what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Maybe you want to create a dictionary of operators and functions: `calc_functions['+'] = lambda x,y : int(x) + int(y)` Then later call it `result = executeFunction(calc_functions[dzialanie], input1, input2))` That way you can catch exceptions for key not found or divide by zero?

Comment: i've tried also with

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this with Harshal Parekh answer

```
        excpetion handler and adding        
        def executeAddition(x, y):
            try:
                z = lambda x, y: int(x) + int(y)
                # you need to execute the lambda, like this:
                return z(x, y)
            except:
                print('Exception caught')

        if str(dzialanie)=='+':
            print("result is: "  + str(executeAddition(input("input 1st number: "), input("input 2nd number: "))))
```

...

Answer (score 0):

i'm adding my whole python calculator with lambda function use.
Exceptions handled in code.
Github repo for this whole console app project is : https://github.com/adamBernat/PythonImperativeProgramming/blob/master/project.py

```
#lambda calculator
def LambdaCalculator():
    quit_l = False
    quit2_l = False
    dzialanie =' '
    while quit_l !=True:
        x=0.0
        y=0.0
        z=0.0
        print("Welcome in calculator")

        while quit2_l != True:
            print("\nto add two numbers type '+'")
            print("to subtract two numbers type '-'")
            print("to multiply two numbers type'*'")
            print("to divide two numbers type '/'")
            print("to exit type 'q'")
            dzialanie=(input('\n which operation you want to choose? '))

            #excpetion handler and adding        
            def executeAddition(x, y):
                try:
                    z = lambda x, y: int(x) + int(y)
                    # you need to execute the lambda, like this:
                    return z(x, y)
                except:
                    print('Exception caught')

            if str(dzialanie)=='+':
                print("result is: "  + str(executeAddition(input("input 1st number: "), input("input 2nd number: "))))


            #excpetion handler and multiplying        
            def executeMultip(x, y):
                try:
                    z = lambda x, y: int(x) * int(y)
                    # you need to execute the lambda, like this:
                    return z(x, y)
                except:
                    print('Exception caught')

            if str(dzialanie)=='*':
                multip = lambda x,y : x * y
                print("result is: "  + str(executeMultip(input("input 1st number: ")), int(input("input 2nd number: "))))

            #excpetion handler and subtracting        
            def executeSubtract(x, y):
                try:
                    z = lambda x, y: float(x) - float(y)
                    # you need to execute the lambda, like this:
                    return z(x, y)
                except:
                    print('Exception caught')

            if str(dzialanie)=='-':
                subtract = lambda x,y : x - y
                print("result is: "  + str(executeSubtract(input("input 1st number: ") , input("input 2nd number: "))))


            #excpetion handler and dividing        
            def executeDiv(x, y):
                try:
                    z = lambda x, y: float(x) / float(y)
                    # you need to execute the lambda, like this:
                    return z(x, y)
                except:
                    print('Exception caught')

            if str(dzialanie)=='/':
                print("result is: "  + str(executeDiv(input("input 1st number: "), input("input 2nd number: "))))




            if str(dzialanie)=='q':
                quit_l = True
                quit2_l = True
                print ("\nsubprogram finished, returning to main menu\n")
                break
            else:
                x=1
```