# How to create a lambda that raises unless its input is an empty list?

Tags: python-3.x, exception, lambda

I would like to create a lambda that raises `ValueError` if its input is a non-empty list.  Based on the answer proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294618/define-a-lambda-expression-that-raises-an-exception]), I implemented it as follows:

```
f = lambda x: (_ for _ in ()).throw(ValueError()) if len(x) != 0 else []
```

(Note that the return value `[]` when `x` is an empty list is not important here, I just had to put something to have a complete `if`-`else` statement.)

That works as intended, but the code looks a bit cryptic.  Is there any nicer way to write the above?  I am thinking about using `x` somehow in the generator `(_ for _ in ())` but am not able to see straightforwardly how to do so in order to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **proper** solution (the ones mentionned in the post you linked to are all complete WTF) is dead simple and pretty obvious: don't use a lambda. "Lambdas" are just syntactic sugar for proper function definitions (they ARE functions, period), used when you only need a very simple one-shot callback. You can pass a proper function (or just any callable) wherever you use a lambda. IOW what you want is:

```
def check_non_empty(lst):
    if not lst:
        raise ValueError("list should not be empty")
    return lst
```

Comment: Thank you.  Indeed, I would feel more comfortable with a proper function as well --- lambda was a wrong choice.