# Best way of asserting an input is of a normally hidden builtin class

Tags: python, types, generator, assert, built-in

In python, there are some built-in classes that are not normally accessible such as Code, NoneType,  and Generator. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66046000/the-name-and-nature-of-the-hidden-builtins-classes-object-function-code-etc) asks about some of these, and the answer essentially seems to be "don't worry about it." However, I specifically want to check if an object passed to my function is a generator function. Currently the relevant structure of my code is as follows.

```
def dummyGen_():
    yield None

Generator = type(dummyGen_())

def myFunct(gen):
   g = gen()
   assert type(g) is Generator
   # rest of the code #
```

However defining a useless generator that doesn't do anything just to get to its type feels awkward, and I just don't like it. Is there a better, more pythonic way of going about this? Or am I doomed to just create a random generator just to access it's type?

Comment: does this help? https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator

Comment: Insisting that your parameter be a generator function is inherently unpythonic.  *Any* iterator fulfills the same interface as a generator, so you're just needlessly restricting the uses of your function.

Comment: @jasonharper that's a good point, and I feel a little silly now, because I entirely forgot iterators are a thing. The only objection I would have, is that I actually need the iterators to never halt, but I suppose that they would throw an objection anyways if they did halt.